# Can't start ubuntu installation

Tags: installation, 12.10, 13.04, mint

I downloaded the ISO from the official Ubuntu site, burnt the ISO to DVD and on restarting, I get the following error-

> start booting from usb device syslinux 3.82

I've tried to install 13.04 and 12.10, but I've faced the same error. Later, I decided to install Linux Mint 15, only to get the same error. I reached the [welcome screen](http://static.howtoforge.com/images/perfect_desktop_mint_14_cinnamon_64bit/1.jpg), but when I select any of the given options, nothing happens and I get this error-

> corrupted kernel image

I decided to check the distros on VirtualBox and they work fine, so where did I go wrong?

Comment: could you describe the process followed to burn the ISO onto the DVD? if there was any error during that process, it may get rectified.

Comment: @Projjol, I use UltraIso on windows 7.Burning always finishs succesfully.

Comment: There might be an issue with the ISO itself then, could you check the MD5sum? You'd have to cd into the directory where the downloaded ISO is & run the command `md5sum download_flie_name.iso`, verify with the hashes given on this [link](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuHashes).

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried those DVD's in Virtualbox ?

If they aren't working in VB then it is a burning software problem.

Comment: He has already mentioned in the question that they work in VirtualBox.

Comment: He has not specified whether he tries ISO images or DVDs.

Comment: I trying iso images

Comment: Well, can you try the DVDs in VirtualBox like what @Pulkit609 mentioned? Maybe the DVDs weren't burned properly. Alternatively, you can install using a USB stick, which is much easier in my opinion.

Comment: when install on usb get this error `start booting from usb device syslinux 3.82`

Comment: @Pulkit609, I try to Dvd in virtual box and it doesn't work. SO this meen that dvd bean with error/ so thanks)

Answer (score 0):

Probably editing the syslinux.cfg file can help you out, you can do the following-

1.Open the the syslinux folder in the root of the flash drive.

2.Inside is a file called syslinux.cfg you’ll want to edit that.

3.Find the line “ui gfxboot bootlogo” and simply remove the “ui “.

4.Save and try booting again.

If that does not work, the following can be tried (found it after going through a few sites, but this isn't a concrete solution really)

1.Type “help” and press enter

2.Hit Enter again

As mentioned, the chances of the second option being viable are really low.